# Spring Data JPA Method - find parent and with conditional children

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm facing this issue while trying to fetch a list of parents with their children filtered.
In my app, users can create carts and for each cart, they will receive one or more commission once they proceed with the payment. When I'm trying to get the carts with its respective commissions, JPA gets me carts with all their commissions if amongst them there's my passed `user_id`.

```java
// Cart Entity
@Entity
public class Cart {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Commission> commissions = new HashSet<>();
}

// Commission Entity
@Entity
public class Commission {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private Cart cart;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}

// Cart Repository
public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Long> {

    Page<Cart> findDistinctByCommissions_User_Id(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

In DB:

```
CART
|--------------|------------------|
|      id      |   description    |...
|--------------|------------------|
|       1      |       ....       |...
|--------------|------------------|
|       2      |       ....       |...
|--------------|------------------|
|       3      |       ....       |...
|--------------|------------------|

COMMISSIONS
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id      |     cart_id      |      user_id     |...
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       1      |        1         |         1        |...
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       2      |        1         |         1        |...
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       3      |        1         |         1        |...
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       4      |        1         |         2        |...
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What I call:

```java
@GetMapping
Page<Cart> getByUserId(Long id, Pageable pageable) {
    return cartRepository.findDistinctByCommissions_User_Id(id, pageable); // 1
}
```

What I get:

```json
{
    "content":[
        {
            id: 1,
            commissions: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 } ]
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

What I want (excluding commission 4 which is not linked with user 1):

```json
{
    "content":[
        {
            id: 1,
            commissions: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ]
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not map the cart with the user as one to one. One user will have one cart right. Once that is done you can directly pass the user object in the data-jpa query.

Comment: Above example is a summarized version of how the app I'm working on is. In my app, a commission is not necessarily linked to a user through a cart since my users are formed in a pyramid structure, meaning that if user A (who has a referral of user B) makes an order X, both user A and B will receive a commission linked to order X.